# Javascript Slickgrid, change row background on row select

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I'm using slickgrid library, I have a grid that I would like it to have the ability of selecting a row on click and then chenge it's background color to red.

I'm using the code below, the grid click event is working I can print in the console the id of each row clicked but I don't know how to change the selected row background.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
  <title>SlickGrid example 1: Basic grid</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/SlickGrid/slick.grid.css" type="text/css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/SlickGrid/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" type="text/css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/exemple.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" width="50%">
      <div id="myGrid" style="width:480px;height:187px;"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script src="js/SlickGrid/lib/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/SlickGrid/lib/jquery.event.drag-2.2.js"></script>

<script src="js/SlickGrid/slick.core.js"></script>
<script src="js/SlickGrid/plugins/slick.rowselectionmodel.js"></script>
<script src="js/SlickGrid/slick.grid.js"></script>


<script>
  var grid;
  var columns = [
    {id: "title", name: "Title", field: "title",selectable: true},
    {id: "duration", name: "Duration", field: "duration"},
    {id: "%", name: "% Complete", field: "percentComplete"},
    {id: "start", name: "Start", field: "start"},
    {id: "finish", name: "Finish", field: "finish"},
    {id: "effort-driven", name: "Effort Driven", field: "effortDriven"}
  ];

  var options = {
    enableCellNavigation: true,
    enableColumnReorder: false
  };

  $(function () {
    var data = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      data[i] = {
        title: "Task " + i,
        duration: "5 days",
        percentComplete: Math.round(Math.random() * 100),
        start: "01/01/2009",
        finish: "01/05/2009",
        effortDriven: (i % 5 == 0)
      };
    }

    grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);
    grid.setSelectionModel(new Slick.RowSelectionModel());
    grid.onClick.subscribe(function (e) {
      var cell = grid.getCellFromEvent(e);
      console.log(cell.row);//Here is the row id, I want to change this row background color
      grid.setSelectedRows(cell.row);
      e.stopPropagation();

    });
  })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is a link to a page if you want to test [Sample Page](http://payclix.biz/MobiusTrac/gridSelection.html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like you're missing a css file. When I load your sample page and look at the console, this file is missing:

```
http://payclix.biz/MobiusTrac/slick-default-theme.css
```

This piece of css would color the row for you:

```
.slick-row.active .slick-cell {
     background-color: #FFB;
}
```

or with jQuery:

```
$(".slick-row").click( function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "#FBB");
});
```

Comment: Hi, this is working thanks but, I would like to do it programaticaly? The id of the active row is something I can find (as shown in the code above) Thanks.

Comment: I added a short jQuery example. You don't need the id to change its background color.

Comment: I actually had to use `$(this).children().css('background-color', '#FBB');` for it to work with the current version.

Comment: I added info on it to the documentation: https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/wiki/Handling-selection#row-selection Now it looks like it is using `.slick-cell.selected`.

Answer (score 1):

Active row has class "active" and you can add properties to the CSS for this class.

Comment: That's what I discovered, added some styling and voila!